# Converting a dict to pandas dataframe, keeping the keys in a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dict like this:

```
x = { 'A': [3.4, 4.2, 5.6]
      'B': [5.6, 7.8, 2.3]
      etc....
    }
```

I want to create a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
'POINT'   'X'   'Y'   'Z'
   A      3.4   4.2   5.6
   B      5.6   7.8   2.3
etc...
```

df=pd.DataFrame(list(x.items())...

yields a 2 column dataframe with the key in column 0 and the value as list in column 1.

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x)

yields a basically correct dataframe, but there is no column for POINT, as I understand it uses that as index. Is there a simple way to achieve this with dict conversion? (I know I can get there with loops through the dict and filling the dataframe cells)
And sorry if this is a stupid question, I have little to no experience with pandas...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(x).T.reset_index()
df.columns = ['POINT', 'X', 'Y',  'Z']
```

Result:

```
print(df)

  POINT    X    Y    Z
0     A  3.4  4.2  5.6
1     B  5.6  7.8  2.3
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can try:

```
x = { 'A': [3.4, 4.2, 5.6],
      'B': [5.6, 7.8, 2.3]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(x).T.rename(columns= {0: 'X', 1: 'Y', 2: 'Z'})
```

OUTPUT:

```
     X    Y    Z
A  3.4  4.2  5.6
B  5.6  7.8  2.3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x, 'index', columns=["X", "Y", "Z"])
```

Output:

```
     X    Y    Z
A  3.4  4.2  5.6
B  5.6  7.8  2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for adding POINT column:

```
points = x.keys()
df['POINT']=points
```

or
df.reset_index()

Comment: what do you mean dic is not order, the dic order is similer to df order. ```import pandas as pd

x = { 'A': [3.4, 4.2, 5.6],
      'B': [5.6, 7.8, 2.3]
    }
df=pd.DataFrame(x).transpose()
keys = x.keys()
df['POINT']=keys ```

Comment: another is that can use reset_index and then just change the new column name to POINTS

Answer (score 0):

```
df_data = [[key] + values for key, values in data_dict.items()]
df = pd.DataFrame(df_data, columns=["POINT", "X", "Y", "Z"])
```